# JSP multipart file upload

Tags: jsp, servlets, multipartform-data

I am facing a problem.

I am trying to upload a file and also get file's link and description.
I know that i need cos or any other utility. I just failed to achieve this 
when i wrote `@MultipartConfig`
the Strings in the servlet with .getParameter returns values
but the code go in infinite loop 
in :

```
`while (totaBytesRead < formDataLength) {
    //do code
}`
```

I saw many other ways but all of them check if formField then insert values or multipart then insert file. 
I need to use both of file and text fields
so please , if any one know the exact solution for my problem i'd be so grateful

Comment: This isn't really enough for us to help you identify and fix whatever problem you have -- if your loop is infinite, that means you're either not decrementing `formDataLength` or incrementing `totaBytesRead`. But there's nothing here to indicate what could be the problem...

Comment: @Dave Newton Well thanks first for your reply 
Secondly : i made in the while body 
_italic_ **bold** `formDataLength--; But no way also :( 
do ou want me to write a more detailed code or ? :)`

Comment: Here is a more detailed code : 

`if((contentType!=null && (conetentType.indexOf("multipart/fprm-data") >=0) {
DataInputStream in = new dataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
int fomrDataLength = request.getContentLength();
byte dataByte[ ] = new byte[formDataLength];
int byteRead=0;
int totalByteRead=0;
while( totalByteRead < formDataLength) {
byteRead =  in.read(dataBytes,totalBytesRead ,  formDataLength);
totaBytesRead +=byteRead;
formDataLength--; // i put this line when you asked if am decremnting this value 
}`

Hope this gonna help ^_^

Comment: Please [edit] that code into the question -- code in comments is illegible at best.

Answer (score 0):

I sugest you to use at least **Apache Commons FileUpload**. And if you will add **Spring** and use **MultipartServletResolver** - your life become easy with multipart form data processing. In that case you will be able process data as plain form data.

Comment: @alexy :  thanks for your reply : **could you just suggest me a single page tutorial using Spring ? am totally new to it . your help is very appreciated :)**